# Let's Encrypt with vert.x

Tags: kotlin, vert.x

I got valid https certificate from Let's Encrypt, but have trust issues giving it to vert.x version 3.6.2

I tested the cert with apache, it's ok, however if I try to reach the https vert.x server instance with wget I get:

> $ wget  https://www.myhost.mydomain/json/read/all-languages
>   
> --2019-01-22 10:30:56--  https://www.myhost.mydomain/json/read/all-languages
>   Resolving www.myhost.mydomain (www.myhost.mydomain)... 88.14.34.156
>   Connecting to www.myhost.mydomain >(www.myhost.mydomain)|88.14.34.156|:443... connected.
>   ERROR: cannot verify www.myhost.mydomain's certificate, issued by >‘CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US’:
>    Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
>   To connect to www.myhost.mydomain insecurely, use `--no-check->certificate'.

Hostname and ip is forged.

my working apache config snippet:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/certs/myhost.mydomain/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/certs/myhost.mydomain/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/certs/myhost.mydomain/chain.pem
```

vert.x code:

```
val httpsOptions = HttpServerOptions()
.setPort(443)
.setSsl(true)
.setPemTrustOptions(PemTrustOptions()
    .addCertPath("/etc/certs/myhost.mydomain/chain.pem"))
.setPemKeyCertOptions(PemKeyCertOptions()
    .addKeyPath("/etc/certs/myhost.mydomain/privkey.pem")
    .addCertPath("/etc/certs/myhost.mydomain/cert.pem")
)
vertx.createHttpServer(httpsOptions).requestHandler(router).listen()
```

I set vert.x logging to debug, but no error message appears.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/android-doesnt-trust-the-certificate/16498/2

I changed the cert.pem to fullchain.pem in the setPemKeyCertOptions settings, and it works.

Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the certificate chain file **chain.pem**. It seems that it does not contain the full certificate chain. If you view the file it probably contains only one intermediate LE authority cert inside, i.e., *Let's Encrypt Authority X3*. It works with Apache because the **SSLCertificateChainFile** is actually [deprecated](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatechainfile) and it is not being used at all.

Vert.x on the other side does use the **chain.pem** file. It returns only the intermediate cert and *wget* complains because of that. To fix the issue create a **fullchain.pem** file composed of both the **chain.pem** and the **cert.pem** files, e.g.,

```
cat cert.pem chain.pem > fullchain.pem
```

Then use the **fullchain.pem** with the *PemTrustOptions* configuration.

You don't need to put the LE root certificate in the **fullchain.pem** file, because it should already be present on both client and server side. Here's an excerpt from the [TLS Protocol RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.2) about it.

> certificate_list
> This is a sequence (chain) of certificates.  The sender's
> certificate MUST come first in the list.  Each following
> certificate MUST directly certify the one preceding it.  Because
> certificate validation requires that root keys be distributed
> independently, the self-signed certificate that specifies the root
> certificate authority MAY be omitted from the chain, under the
> assumption that the remote end must already possess it in order to
> validate it in any case.

Comment: I was trying to change chain.pem to fullchain.pem in the PemTrustOptions configuration, and tried even without PemTrustOptions, but I get the same result. I tested it now again, no change... :S

Comment: I also checked https with fullchain.pem on https://www.ssllabs.com and it says: Chain issues Incomplete

Comment: @Ebadta What does your fullchain.pem contain? It should contain two blocks of PEM encoded data. Each block is surrounded by -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -----END CERTIFICATE-----. Can you confirm this?